# How to create a generator with Projen from scratch?

Tags: node.js, devops

I love the idea of [Projen](https://github.com/projen/projen/tree/b9152631d7f79d83df175cda497fe3f01cb3b46f), however, I could not fin a guide on building a generator from absolute scratch. I have a totally custom project template that I would like to automate bootstrapping it.

Is there such guide around? Can you create a short one?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? Do you have some repo example of what you have and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @thoroc No. I decided to take the completely manual approach, not relying on any additional tool.

Comment: It might be possible to use your custom project using the `--from` flag: https://github.com/projen/projen#projects-in-external-modules. I don't know if that was already there 2 years ago.

Comment: @thoroc eh.. ‍♂️ I'm happy with the flexibility I got by doing things manually